# Notation for dominating (or uniformly bounded) function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, asymptotics, notation

While I developing a new statistical estimator, I wondered is there any good notation for dominating (or uniformly bounded) function.

A situation like this. For some true function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, I have got an estimated function $\hat{f}$ whose error is bounded by $g$, that is,
$$
   |\hat{f}(x) - f(x)|≤ Cg(x)
$$
Of course that the error $\hat{f} - f$ is clearly bounded by $g$ uniformly in $x$.
Now, similar to the Big-O notation, I want to express this as something like
$$
  \hat{f}(x) = f(x) + \bigstar(g(x)).
$$
This kind of notation would be very useful because we can just handle the term $\bigstar$ without any inequalities. (As what Big-O notation does. But in here it is uniformly bounded by $g$.)

I do not know is there any good notation for this in analysis or probability, but if so, it would be much better to use it rather than my $\bigstar$ notation.

It would be appreciated if you know any kind of notation for this.

Thanks,